# what is good book (linear algebra) for all aspects tensor contractions?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I need to study inside and ouut of tensor contractions, what is good linear algebra book? In school, I took only once linear algebra class but topic never covered contractions. Is there a specific linear algebra branch that teaches it?

Comment: A contraction tensor is the tensor product of a finite dimensional space and its duel.

Comment: Presumably you learned matrix vector multiplication in your linear algebra class. This can be written in [index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction#Contraction_in_index_notation) as $(Mv)_i=\sum_{j=1}^nM_{ij}v_j=M_{ij}v^j$ (summation convention). This is already the first tensor contraction you presumably have seen in that LA class. Contractions of higher order tensors are no more complicated than that and imho a book to learn this from is not needed. The Wikipedia link I posted should get you started.